# Recover data sent via websocket

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, pyqt5, python-asyncio

I use Websockets to retrieve data for further processing.
I can't figure out how to retrieve it outside of my class.
I use the thread module to separate the websocket from the rest of the program so I can run a pyqt5 application where I display the processed data but I can't retrieve it.

Maybe I should use something other than threads but I don't have an idea.
Since I can receive a lot of data and have a lot of work to do on it, calculations, display etc. I try to make it a minimum optimized otherwise it will never be able to handle all my requests per second.

```
import websockets
import asyncio
import json
import threading
import time


class WS(object):
    def __init__(self, serveur):
        self.serveur = serveur

    async def connect(self):

        async with websockets.connect(self.serveur) as websocket:
            while True:
                message = await websocket.recv()
                self.data = json.loads(message)
                print(self.data)


uri = "wss://www.bitmex.com/realtime?subscribe=instrument:XBTUSD"
ws = WS(uri)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
th1 = threading.Thread(target=lambda: loop.run_until_complete(ws.connect()))
th1.start()

while True:  # My application that will display and process the data retrieved by the websocket.
    print('blabla')
    time.sleep(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

By default Qt does not support eventloops because in those cases using threading is usually a valid workaround, but in these cases it is better to use libraries such as [`qasync`](https://github.com/CabbageDevelopment/qasync)(`python -m pip install qasync`) and [`asyncqt`](https://github.com/gmarull/asyncqt)(`python -m pip install asyncqt`). Considering that case, a possible solution is to use the Qt signals to send the information.

```py
import asyncio
import json
import websockets

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from asyncqt import QEventLoop


class WS(QtCore.QObject):
    dataChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(dict)

    def __init__(self, server, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._server = server

    @property
    def server(self):
        return self._server

    async def connect(self):

        async with websockets.connect(self.server) as websocket:
            while True:
                message = await websocket.recv()
                data = json.loads(message)
                self.dataChanged.emit(data)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.text_edit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.text_edit)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(dict)
    def update_data(self, data):
        # only for test
        text = json.dumps(data)
        self.text_edit.setPlainText(text)


def main():
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    loop = QEventLoop(app)
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

    uri = "wss://www.bitmex.com/realtime?subscribe=instrument:XBTUSD"
    ws = WS(uri)

    w = MainWindow()
    ws.dataChanged.connect(w.update_data)
    w.show()

    with loop:
        loop.create_task(ws.connect())
        loop.run_forever()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Update:

```py
import asyncio
import json
import websockets

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from asyncqt import QEventLoop, asyncSlot


class WS(QtCore.QObject):
    dataChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(dict)

    def __init__(self, server, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._server = server
        self._websocket = None

    @property
    def websocket(self):
        return self._websocket

    async def connect(self):
        self._websocket = await websockets.connect(self._server)
        await self.ready_read()

    async def ready_read(self):
        while True:
            message = await self.websocket.recv()
            data = json.loads(message)
            self.dataChanged.emit(data)

    @asyncSlot(dict)
    async def send_message(self, message):
        data = json.dumps(message)
        await self.websocket.send(data)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    sendMessageSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(dict)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Press me")
        self.text_edit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        lay.addWidget(self.button)
        lay.addWidget(self.text_edit)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_clicked(self):
        auth_data = {"op": "subscribe", "args": ["instrument:XBTUSD"]}
        self.sendMessageSignal.emit(auth_data)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(dict)
    def update_data(self, data):
        # only for test
        text = json.dumps(data)
        self.text_edit.setPlainText(text)


def main():
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    loop = QEventLoop(app)
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

    uri = "wss://www.bitmex.com/realtime?subscribe=instrument:XBTUSD"
    ws = WS(uri)

    w = MainWindow()
    ws.dataChanged.connect(w.update_data)
    w.sendMessageSignal.connect(ws.send_message)
    w.show()

    with loop:
        loop.create_task(ws.connect())
        loop.run_forever()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: @antho What you want is not trivial, I recommend you first learn how Asyncio and PyQt works, and when you know both technologies well then try using both as my updated example shows. If you add more requirements then I will no longer respond, in that case you will have to create a new post indicating what you have tried

Comment: @antho I have no links, but my recommendation already pointed out in my previous comment.